# How to set highlight color for p:treeTable

Tags: css, primefaces, treetable

Is there a way to override Primefaces treetable highlight color?

Not working examples:

```
tr:hover {
    background: #FF0000;
}
.ui-state-hover {
    background: #FF0000;
}
.ui-widget-content:hover {
    background: #FF0000;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "!important"?

```
tr:hover {
    background: #FF0000!important;
}
.ui-state-hover {
    background: #FF0000!important;
}
.ui-widget-content:hover {
    background: #FF0000!important;
}
.ui-state-highlight {
    background: #FF0000!important;
}
```

This will overwrite any CSS calling the same thing such as auto generated css.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this type of problem with:

```
tr.ui-state-highlight .ui-widget-content{
    color:white;
}
```

Maybe you are able to use a css-class to minimize the amount of effected elements, but not shure. =)